# iTunes Search for a Song X Many Minutes Long

Tags: itunes, search

Can I search for a song in my music library that is between x and y start and end times, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible by creating a smart playlist.

Below the playlist sidebar click on the plus-button and choose to add a new smart playlist. You can set it something like this:
[image: Screenshot of a Smart Playlist]